# Concerns with long-distance driving

Tags: driving, solo-travel, domestic-travel

I am planning on taking my mid-life vehicle (~100,000 miles) on a long distance drive (~1,200 miles) over the course of a couple of days.

I don't have much experience with car mechanics or long-distance driving. I rarely get on the highway or take my car above 70 mph.

What kind of stresses would such a drive press on a vehicle? Should I be concerned for anything, i.e. is long-distance driving harmful to a vehicle? If so, what contingencies could I prepare?

For the record, my vehicle is a 2011 Hyundai Elantra.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76665/discussion-on-question-by-b-fox-concerns-with-long-distance-driving).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Take your car to a mechanic and get it looked at.  Make sure that all belts and hoses are in good condition, and all fluids are topped up.  Make sure you know the rate at which your engine burns oil, so you know how often to check it, and carry spare oil with you.  Make sure your tires have plenty of tread and are properly inflated, and have no sidewall damage, and monitor the tire pressure regularly.  Ideally, carry a spare tire and jack and wrench, but a lot of newer cars don't come with these anymore, which is lamentable.

Other than that, you don't have to do very much, as long as the vehicle is in good shape.

Last year I took my then ten-year-old Honda over 5,000 km (~3100 mi.) from Saskatchewan to see the eclipse and visit the US west coast, and other than two stone chips on the windshield, I had no problems.  This year I'm taking it almost 6,000 km (~3725 mi.) to Texas via Kansas City, and back via Santa Fe, Denver and Deadwood, and I'm not terribly worried.  There is a chance I could have a failure, but that is possible with a newer car, too.  (My car has just over 192,000 km (~119,300 mi.) on it.)

Drive safely - know your route in advance if possible.  Be well rested, take adequate breaks for food, drink and bathroom relief (and resting your eyes and body), and enjoy the trip.  Make sure you have a fully-charged phone with you in case you have trouble, and carry lots of water, especially in the summer, in case you get thirsty in an isolated area.

Comment: This is assuring and quite the answer I was looking for: one from experience. I figured that the automotive industry imagined people taking their vehicles across large distances, and thus factored that into their vehicles' reliability, though I wanted to learn about any potential dangers. Taking the car to a mechanic is a great idea, I will probably follow that advice (my car does occasionally make an odd noise, so there's two reasons). Thank you

Comment: @B.fox Modern vehicles are a lot more reliable than they once were.  One other thing: make sure you have good tires, and make sure to check their inflation regularly.

Comment: @B.fox One other thing: the biggest dangers are inattention and fatigue.  Pay close attention to everything on the road, avoid distraction where possible, and be well rested.  Don't drive further than your body and mind will let you.

Comment: @Jim MacKenzie's advice above is particularly apt for the OP, a driver who has little experience with long trips.

Comment: With long distance trips, there's also the possibility that you'll end up driving in weather and conditions that you're not used to. High winds, icing, torrential downpours, steep grades, sheer drops with no shoulder, etc. Just from personal experience :-)

Comment: Regarding @JimMacKenzie's note, if OP is really going to do 1200 miles in 2 days, that's going to be close to 10 hours per day behind the wheel.  I think even many experienced drivers would find it hard to stay alert for a day that long.  I'd encourage OP to adjust the itinerary to allow for more travel time.

Comment: @NateE, it depends on what kind of experience the driver has. I have found that 5 minute stops every two hours or so with a good audiobook lets me go for 13-15 hours no problem. But some people just get tired very easily.

Comment: While this is all good advice, I would be very surprised if you needed to top-up oil or tyre pressure after just 1200 miles.

Comment: @MartinBonner Small gasket leaks could use up some oil

Comment: @user128216 most people get tired after so many hours no matter how ofter they rest. This is the reason the driving time for truck drivers is legally restricted and enforced by registering devices.

Comment: @MartinBonner Questions and answers on Travel.SE aren't just for the original poster - anyone going on a trip of any length should, at a minimum, check the oil before they go, and if they're going far enough, during the trip as well.  My car is old enough that on a 5,000 km trip, I probably need to add a litre of oil toward the end.

Comment: @9ilsd: Tired, yes, but that doesn't mean you can't drive. Commercial driving is different and I feel should be held to higher standards because it's something they do _every day_. I used to make occasional weekend trips to see the folks on a Friday night and back home on Sunday at noon, with a 10+ hour drive each way, and never got so tired that I felt I couldn't drive. Like I said, it depends on the person. Obviously, stop driving if you feel like you can't drive safely.

Comment: Mention any little irritations to the mechanic when you book it in.  Example: My 2003 Transit camper had become even slower up hill and noisier than I was used to. It turned out to need a new injector pump.  Expensive but probably a good idea with a trip to the mountains coming up.

Comment: I've done a fair bit of distance driving (ID to IN or NY, solo or tandem, IN to NC/SC solo and groups) multiple times. Most of those drives have been in vehicles with over 100k miles. It's not the vehicle's mileage, it's the maintenance that's important. Since this is your first distance trip and especially if you are going solo, plan on stopping every 2-3 hours to stretch, get a bit of food and rest. The constant vibration (even in a brand spankin' new car <10k miles) will wear you out much faster than you realize.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie While it is good to make an answer suitable for more than just the original poster, it is also a good idea to clarify which parts are *not* for the OP.  Given a car that has just been checked over, a drive of  1200 miles / 2000 km doesn't justify an oil check.

Comment: @MartinBonner With modern direct-injection engines, I don't think that's a safe assumption at all.

Comment: Oil: I had a vintage 2001 Skoda Octavia and I had to top up the oil every 1000 km. I kept a bottle in the boot for long journeys.

Answer (score 41):

You might want to consider a membership to a roadside assistance plan, which will at least give you a number to call for 24/7 repair services or towing should you have a problem during your trip.

Comment: In Canada, I have found CAA to provide excellent service for a very reasonable cost. Actually, I've never actually gotten my own membership, but just borrowed a family member's card when I needed it (3 tows over four years). 'Course, that only works if you break down locally, so I'd suggest getting the 200km+ option which costs a bit more if OP plans on driving in remote areas. CAA is a partner company to AAA in the US.

Comment: This! My parents had their 10 year old car break down 3000 km from home, a week into their 3 week trip. Since the water pump had melted (yep) it was a totall loss. Their roadside assistance (ANWB, also an AAA partner company) took care of demolishing their old car and allowed them to borrow a brand new car for a month, so they could finish their trip and look for a new car when they got home.

Comment: This was the first thing that occurred to me when I read the question.  If you're worried about a risk torpedoing a plan, insure against it, then proceed with your original plan.

Comment: @Belle-Sophie How did they manage to do that? I've run old ('62) car dry for several kilometers in summer. There was no cooling water in the system even to develop a steam. After refill and replacing the safety cap in the pump the car was OK. First attempt to refill hid whole car in a steam cloud...

Comment: @Crowley I'm not sure. Why don't we discuss this in chat? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here

Answer (score 16):

A lot of wear and tear happens when you drive while the engine is still cold. On a long distance drive, your engine will be at its optimal temperature most of the time.

A lot of wear and tear happens when you accelerate and slow down, use the brakes, the clutch, etc. On a long distance drive, you might be two hours on the motorway without ever braking or shifting gears.

So, the wear and tear, and the chances of breaking down, are less than if you did the same distance 5 miles at a time over many weeks.

Comment: Agree with this answer, but I want to add, watch out for issues that only show up after driving for more than a few miles. My friend's car overheated the first time we drove a long distance in it, because he'd never driving it more than a couple miles and the radiator was faulty.

Answer (score 11):

This may sound strange, but have you considered renting a car for the trip?  Rentals are usually well maintained and a mid size car with unlimited miles will cost less than the cost of a tuneup.

Comment: Not strange at all. AAA publishes [a guide](https://exchange.aaa.com/automotive/driving-costs/) that allows a rough estimation of the per-mile cost of driving various classes of vehicles. It can often be cheaper in the long run to rent for drives in the thousands of miles.

Comment: For a small sedan like an Elantra, maintenance+depreciation runs about 21 cents per mile, so a 1200-mile drive might be around $250, which is probably more expensive than a 2-day rental with unlimited mileage.

Comment: I did this when my kids were small. I'd rent a big Cadillac with plenty of room for everyone plus luggage. Cramming everyone into one of our small cars would not have been pleasant for anyone. First time I had a car set to 100mph on cruise control. Wheee!

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other answers I'd suggest planning for the contingency that you need to split the drive over 3 days instead of 2, if you find you are getting tired or making slower progress than expected.

So, know where you'd head if you had to break for the night after 6 or 8 hours instead of 10 (or sitting in an unexpected traffic jam for several hours).

Then you can adjust your plans if necessary and stop in a town with food and rest available, rather than finding out halfway across a mountain pass that your eyes won't stay open any longer.

Answer (score 6):

[Technically, the question is about the vehicle, but I venture that a human being of good judgement would allow it.]

Not that it will *actually help*, but... you need to be aware that your reaction time will be dulled by about 2 to 1.5 (additional) seconds.  [This is from personal experience, not science.]

Also (since I'm here)... if you are getting tired... I have found that annoying music is *far* less effective than enjoyable music; pick something that you *want* to sing along to.  (This is *not* to be taken as explicit advice to push on when you are tired.)

More subjectively... I find that it is a sign of getting tired, that I am less able to stick to the speed limit effectively, and to follow my desired line on corners; I would not immediately take this as an indication to pull off the road, but certainly as a flag.  If and when it gets worse, pull over!  [Pardon me speaking strongly.]  (I am speaking as a then-full-time driver; I do not know how it translates, for someone who does not normally drive for hours.)

Comment: If you are tired, pull over and sleep! Drowsy driving is drunk driving.  Rural cops get it, and don't hassle sleepers.

Comment: This!  The vehicle is only part of the system, the driver is another part of the system.  OP must consider the complete package, not just the mechanicals.

Comment: _pick something that you want to sing along to._ this makes my long drives enjoyable

Answer (score 3):

I've driven my Opel Corsa 1.3 CDTi (I don't remember the exact year it was manufactured but it would've been in the early 2000s) that at that point in time already had a mileage of more than 250,000 KM (250 thousand kilometers) across Europe twice ([from Croatia to Netherlands and back](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Labin,+Croatia/The+Hague,+Netherlands/@48.5061774,4.9071098,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x4763492e71660f7d:0xa1d08ec99dadb953!2m2!1d14.1238049!2d45.091589!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c5b72f4298bd71:0x400de5a8d1e6c10!2m2!1d4.3006999!2d52.0704978!3e0)) which is 1420 KM each way without a problem. The car has always been properly maintained, the roads were in perfect condition, and I was traveling in the summertime. Furthermore, those were trips where I only took small brakes to refuel, eat and stretch my legs.

Like others have said, it's all about the condition. Planes can be 30 years old and more, but if they're properly maintained there's no reason to decommission them.

To answer your question, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from all the other good advice, keep an eye on the car's engine temperature gauge and plan to stop as soon as you can safely do so if it exceeds the normal temperature. Failure to do so will quickly destroy your car, or at least total it in the sense that it's economically impractical to repair unless you know how to do all the work yourself.

If you absolutely need to keep going for a while in a vehicle that's overheating because you don't feel safe where you are, turn the AC off and the heater on full blast. Depending on the cause of the overheating, this might be able to dissipate enough heat that you don't destroy your engine immediately.

Another possible failure mode (which I once experienced) on long trips is loss of transmission fluid due to seal failure. The likely symptom is feeling like the car barely speeds up when you press the accelerator. If this happens you want to stop and get a tow. I kept driving (topping off the transmission fluid again and again) and ended up needing a transmission rebuild (likely over $2500 in 2018 dollars) rather than just a seal replacement.

Comment: The #1 thing that will spike your engine temperature gauge is running the air conditioning while working the engine hard, e.g. climbing a grade.  (And people are often oblivious of being on a grade.) However the usual failure mode is radiator boil over, which is spectacular and most people stop immediately, before engine failure occurs. I would also say looking at your engine temp gauge is useless unless you know what "normal" looks like. So watch it regularly, before you have trouble.

Comment: @Harper: Rather than boil-over you can burst a hose. If you're at highway speed with ac on internal recirculation and the burst spraying down you may not see or smell it. Head gasket failure is also a real possibility and you won't see the coolant loss because it goes out the exhaust.

Answer (score 2):

If you maintain your vehicle well and it's mechanically sound, then there shouldn't be any issues. My car is 13 years old. We've had it for 12 of those 13 years. I live in the central U.S. My car went over 100,000 miles (160,000 km) during the middle of a 4,000 mile (6,400 km) round-trip to the west coast. It went over 125,000 miles (200,000 km) during a 1,300 mile (2,000 km) round-trip to the east coast. It went over 150,000 miles (240,000 km) during a 1,000 mile (1,600 km) round-trip to New Orleans.

I currently have 185,000 miles (almost 300,000 km) on this car. It needs some suspension work, a new power steering pump, and new tires. With that work, I would have complete confidence in driving it on a similar trip.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the additional stress.  First, running at real speed, i.e. 70-80 mph. .  Second, sustained high power operation.  Doing both  for the first time will expose existing flaws in the car.  So do these things early and often, well before the trip, to shake the bugs out of the car.

Western rural speed limits are 75-85, however it is rare for traffic to exceed that. Traffic is mostly trucks, and their fuel cost goes up a lot with speed.

Once your car is happily cruising and stable, it should be relatively stable.  Just as aircraft rarely have a problem in cruise, constant speed cruising for a car is easy service.  The only things which wear worse are tires and suspension.

Comment: 130 km/h are not very fast for most modern cars, and definitely not something requiring "high power". Many cars approach Vmax of 200km/h at full power, which requires about 2.4x the power of 130km/h, or the other way around: In this case you only use about 40% of the max power output of the engine when going 130km/h.

Comment: @JimmyB Aside from meaning "high power" **relative to what *his* engine normally does**... the American West has a triple whammy which gobbles up that 40% in a hurry. First, much is on high steppe of 4000-8000' which derates your aspirated engine by 20-30%.  Second you're on grades a lot, and even 1-2% drags you down.  Third is [the wind](https://imgur.com/gallery/XVfsclN).  My little car with stickshift (I keep it in top gear) often spends hours at a time at WOT (gas to floor)  unable to attain the speed limit. Still gets 30+ MPG, so, not complaining.